# How to speed up min/max aggregates in Postgres without an index that is unnecessary otherwise

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Say I have a table with an `int` column, and all I am ever going to read from it is the MAX() int value.

If I create an index on that column, Postgres can perform a reverse scan of that index to get the `MAX()` value. But since all except one row in the index are just an overhead, can we get the same performance without having to create the full index.

Yes, one can create a trigger to update a single-row table that tracks the MAX value, and query that table instead of issuing a `MAX()` against the main table. But I am looking for something elegant, because I know Postgres has partial indexes, and I can't seem to find a way to leverage them for this purpose.

Update: This partial-index definition is ideally what I'd like, but Postgres does not allow subqueries in the WHERE clause of a partial-index.

`create index on test(a) where a = (select max(a) from test);`

Answer (score 11):

You **cannot** use aggregate functions or subquery expressions in the [**predicate of a partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html). That would make no sense logically anyway, given the `IMMUTABLE` nature of index entries.

If you have a range of integers and you can **guarantee** that the maximum will always be greater than `x`, you can benefit from this meta-information, though.

```
CREATE INDEX text_max_idx ON test (a) WHERE a > x;
```

This index will only be used by the query planner if you include a `WHERE` clause that matches the index predicate. For instance:

```
SELECT max(a) FROM test WHERE a > x;
```

There can be more conditions, but this one has to be included to use the index. (`WHERE a > x + 123` would work, too.)

I am serious about "guarantee", though. Your query will return nothing if the predicate is false.

You could build in a fail-safe:

```
SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT max(a) FROM test WHERE a > x)
               , (SELECT max(a) FROM test));
```

You can generalize this approach with more than one partial index. Similar to this answer, just *a lot* simpler:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22500/3684)

I would consider the trigger approach, except for very heavy write loads on the table.

Answer (score 7):

The other rows in the index are not unnecessary because they enable you to keep the max accurate even in case of deletions, or in case of updates reducing the current maximum.

If you don't have such operations (IOW the max only ever increases) you can maintain the max value yourself. Do it in the application code or in a trigger.

Postgres cannot know that the max will only ever increase. It has to uphold the capability to do deletes and updates.

Comment: I understand, and completely agree with why those other rows (actually [key:pointer_to_row] pairs) are necessary to be kept around. I was implying that they were unnecessary from the application's perspective, as it only ever needs the highest value from the column.

Comment: Does your application ever delete rows or update column a to a lesser value? In that case how is Postgres (or yourself using a trigger) supposed to calculate the new max without scanning the entire table?